# Using python 3 or specifying python executable path to use minted package?

Tags: minted

I wish to use `minted` package also in Windows, however, I have Python 3 installed in my Windows and added to `PATH`. I do not wish `python` command be overridden by Python 2 executable.

So, is there any method to specify Python 2 executable path for `minted` package or use Python 3? Can docker be the solution?

Comment: you can use minted with python3, why do you want to use python2? (does it still work with python2?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh I thought Pygments was installed in default. Then, is there any way to specify python executable path? I don't want to contaminate the environment by installing Pygments globally

Comment: I just install pygmentize but you can place it anywhere and define `\MintedPygmentize` to be the full path to run a command not in your path

Answer (score 3):

Pygments works with python3 (unless you have an ancient copy)

If you choose not to install `pygmentize` in your system path you can redefine `\MintedPygmentize` to be the full path eg

```
\renewcommand\MintedPygmentize{\string\users\string\foo\string\whatever\string\pygmentize}
```

but adding the pygments directory to your path seems easier and keeps  the document portable.